# jquery radio button each -not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to loop through the radio buttons by name with 'each' function..the each function is not working and it is applying the logic only once and it is not looping for the next time..
My use case is, when user selects value from the select dropdown, needs to enable both the radio buttons and if the user deselects the dropdown- needs to disable back..

Here in my case, each function is looping only once and after that it is getting exit from it..Need help in figuring disable/enable based on dropdown selection..

html code:-

```
    <div class="uriDiv input-group">
  <select class="common authSelect form-control" name="authType" id="authType">
    <option value="">
      <spring:message code="newPolicy.selectAuthType"></spring:message>
    </option>
    <option value="DB">DB</option>
    <option value="LDAP">LDAP</option>
  </select>
</div>
<td>
  <div class="auth-permission-rd">
    <div class="uriDiv radio radio-left">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="common anyuser" value="anyUser" name="authPermission" id="authPermission" disabled="disabled">Any User
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="uriDiv radio radio-input">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="common groupuser" value="groupUser" name="authPermission" id="authPermission" disabled="disabled">
        <input type="text" name="authPermissionValue" disabled="disabled" class="common form-control-placeHolder" id="authPermissionValue" placeholder="Enter custom Permissions - Comma separated" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

jquery:

```
  $("#authType").change(function(){
     if($(this).val()){ 
         $("input:radio[name='authPermission']").each(function(){
             $("#authPermission").prop('disabled',false);
                $("#authPermission").prop('checked',false);

         });
     }
     else{
         $("#authPermission").each(function(){
             $("#authPermission").prop('disabled',true);
                $("#authPermission").prop('checked',false);

         });
     }  
});
```

Comment: You cannot have more than one element with the same `id` attribute, nor can you enable more than one radio button with the same `name` value.

Comment: ooh..ok..So, the only possibility is to define separate name/id to each radio button...?

Comment: You do not need IDs at all there, use classes and/or data attributes.

Comment: didnt go you Grisza..can u explain further..!!

Comment: @kotasrinu use the same class to group the elements (i.e. `class="authPermission"`)

Comment: `id` attribute is unique 'An identifier is a name that identifies (that is, labels the identity of) either a unique object...' in other words id is for one element, class is for all elements which belong to class, there is a explanation and hint `getElementById` notice only one element and `getElementsByClassName` notice elements

Comment: @wmash..thanks adding the class, makes it work..can i know how it is making the difference..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have more than one element with the same ID. So, I would change your code by removing the id attribute and putting a new value for the class attribute, then fetch the object using jquery class selector.

```
       <div class="uriDiv input-group">
  <select class="common authSelect form-control" name="authType" id="authType">
    <option value="">
      <spring:message code="newPolicy.selectAuthType"></spring:message>
    </option>
    <option value="DB">DB</option>
    <option value="LDAP">LDAP</option>
  </select>
</div>
<td>
  <div class="auth-permission-rd">
    <div class="uriDiv radio radio-left">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="common anyuser authPermission" value="anyUser" name="authPermission" disabled="disabled">Any User
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="uriDiv radio radio-input">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="common groupuser authPermission" value="groupUser" name="authPermission" disabled="disabled">
        <input type="text" name="authPermissionValue" disabled="disabled" class="common form-control-placeHolder authPermissionValue" placeholder="Enter custom Permissions - Comma separated" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And jQuery code :

```
 $("#authType").change(function(){
     if($(this).val()){ 
         $("input:radio[name='authPermission']").each(function(elemId, elem){
             $(elem).prop('disabled',false);
             $(elem).prop('checked',false);

         });
     }
     else{
         $(".authPermission").each(function(elemId, elem){
             $(elem).prop('disabled',true);
             $(elem).prop('checked',false);
         });
     }  
});
```

But, if we take a better look at your code, I do not understand why you want to use "each". You can achieve the same thing without it :

```
 // Following code :
$(".authPermission").each(function(elemId, elem){
                 $(elem).prop('disabled',true);
                 $(elem).prop('checked',false);
             });
// Does the same thing as this one :
$(".authPermission").prop('disabled', true).prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: yea, it did worked Scalpweb..thanks for it..Here i have one doubt..How jquery is going to distinguish b/w the name and class , when we define both with same name as authPermission..Can you pls explain on how adding the class as authPermission, made it to work..?

Comment: jQuery is finding elements based on the selector you give to it.
To find an element by class, use the "." selector :
$(".YourClassNameHere");
To find an element by id, use the "#" selector :
$("#YourIdHere");
And to find it by name, you can use this (but it will be slower) :
$("[name=YourNameHere]");
More info : https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: because jquery's `$("#authPermission")` is shorthand for js' `getElementById('authPermission')` **get only one element**

Comment: @Scalpweb..ok got it..But adding the class with 'authPermission' for both of them is making a diff..when i removed the class, both are enabling, but when is deselect the dropdown, it is not disabling..

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code. Also enables the input field when the appropriate radio is clicked. This sould work:

```
function updateUI() {

    var select = $("#authType");
    var value = select.val();

    var should_appear = (value.length == 0);

    $("input:radio[name='authPermission']").attr('disabled',should_appear);
}

//binding...

$("input:radio").on("click", function() {
    var should_display_textbox = !($(this).val() === "groupUser");
    console.log(should_display_textbox);
    $("input:text[name='authPermissionValue']").attr('disabled', should_display_textbox);
});

$("#authType").change(function(){
    updateUI();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    updateUI(); //update also when page load
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
 $("#authType").change(function(){
     var disabled = !$(this).val() ? true : false;
     $("input:radio[name='authPermission']").each(function(){
         $(this).prop('disabled', disabled );
         $(this).prop('checked',false);

     });
 });
```